# return handler(fd) IOError: error reading PNG header

Tags: python, matplotlib, png, decision-tree

I am trying to build a Regression tree in Python using an existing code here, https://github.com/mgckind/MLZ/blob/master/mlz/ml_codes/TPZ.py. Specifically Rtree() in the code.

[This is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVIF1.png) I am running to build a tree, which calls the TPZ program.
Where I have a problem is in Plotting the tree, when I call T.plot_tree(). [This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yawiW.png) I got when tried running the program. The author of the code says it was build for a linux environment. So I installed a linux environment in windows(using /lxrun method)but being a layman in coding, I haven't really been able to solve this. Can anyone help me?

Apologies if the information is insufficient and please let me know if there is anything else you require.

Thanks!

edit: This is the code I used. The original issue I had before this was not getting the right path. I then installed the linux environment in windows and was able to solve this issue. But now the issue seems to be in reading the PNG file. Is there an issue with how I've installed the python package Matplotlib for this? I hope this helps!

```
   from numpy import *
   import time
   import os, sys

   path_src = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '../../'))
   if not path_src in sys.path: sys.path.insert(1, path_src)

   from ml_codes import *
   start = time.time()
   X = loadtxt('Data/Query3.txt', usecols=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), unpack=True).T
   Y = loadtxt('Data/Query3.txt', unpack=True, usecols=(8))

   d = {'u': {'ind': 0}, 'g': {'ind': 1}, 'r': {'ind': 2}, 'i': {'ind': 3}, 
   'z': {'ind': 4}, 'u-g': {'ind': 5},
   'g-r': {'ind': 6}}

    T = TPZ.Rtree(X, Y, minleaf=1,forest = 'yes', mstar=4, dict_dim = d)
    T.plot_tree()
    branches = T.leaves()
    att = T.leaves_dim()    
    print 'tree structure = ', branches
    print 'best split at each node = ', att
```

Comment: Please provide the code in text form such that it can be copied and run. See [mcve].

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Apologies I've added the code now. Hope its sufficient and thanks for the link!

Comment: I think the problem is that you do not have graphviz installed or at least not in your $PATH.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I had installed Graphviz using pip as a python package.  I also tried downloading the Graphviz package from [here](http://wingraphviz.sourceforge.net/wingraphviz/) and installed it in the same directory as the code. I'm still getting the same error.